# How do I run Gimp on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, x11

I recently upgraded to Mountain Lion and tried to open GIMP.  To my dismay my computer asked me where X11 was.

How do I find X11 and run GIMP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple decided not to include X11 in Mountain Lion: [Apple Support Article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293)

But there is now a native version of GIMP for mountain lion which requires no X11:
[Gimp Downloads](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

However, if you need to run the old version of GIMP you can download [xquartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) as mentioned in the apple support document linked above.

When you try to run GIMP again, you can find Xquartz in

`/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app`

Enjoy GIMP!

Comment: Actually, once you have Xquartz installed, you usually don't even need to know where it is, since it gets launched automagically whenever some X11 program runs.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen included that because my computer prompted me for the location of X11

Answer (score 4):

The X11 Gimp is actually quite misbehaved on OS X, to the point of being almost totally unusable. But despair not; there is a native Gimp version that doesn't require X11. You can find it on the [Gimp download page](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/).

Comment: Not available at your linked page anymore it seems

Comment: @NicolasRaoul There does seem to be native Gimp 2.8 for OS X there, though I didn't actually try to download it. But it showed up after a short delay; perhaps the server does some browser sniffing, maybe even some javascript magic, before you get to see the downloads? Perhaps you could try a different browser and see if you get a different result.

Comment: Indeed! Browsing from Ubuntu I am only shown Linux/BSD/Solaris downloads. I should have spot the "Other downloads" link, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html you can download a native GIMP 2.8.2 and also the docs. No X11 is required.